# Maintain attribute names when merging Igraphs

Tags: r, merge, igraph

## Problem

I have two separate networks with no overlapping nodes or edges, they both have the same attributes. I want to combine these two networks into a single network which would then be made up of two distinct components.

However when I try to merge them using the `union` command the attributes are renamed from "attribute" to "attribute_1" and "attribute_2". That this will happen is stated in the command help file, but I cannot find an obvious way to merge these two networks.

The situation is shown in the below code block

```
library(igraph)

#create a 4 node network of two components
adjmat <- rep(0, 16)
adjmat[c(2,5,12,15)] <- 1
g <-  graph.adjacency(matrix(adjmat, nrow = 4) , mode = "undirected") 

#give attributes naming the nodes and the edges
g <- set_vertex_attr(g, "name", value = paste0("Node_", 1:4))
g <- set_edge_attr(g, "name", value = paste0("Edge_",1:2))

#I am interested in the type attribute
g <- set_edge_attr(g, "type", value = c("foo", "bar"))

plot(g)

#Decompose into seperate networks
gList <- decompose(g)

g2 <-union(gList[[1]], gList[[2]])

#vertices are fine but edges have been renamed as stated in the helpfile for union.
get.edge.attribute(g2)
get.vertex.attribute(g2)
```

## Work around

Currently the two separate networks originate from the same original network so I have been able to make a hack however this isn't always the case and I would like a more igraph way of merging the two.

The hack is below

```
#To solve this problem I do the following

#Create two dataframes from the edge characteristics of the network and combine into a single dataframe
P <- rbind(as_data_frame(gList[[1]]),
               as_data_frame(gList[[2]]))

g3 <- set.edge.attribute(g, "type", value = P$type[match(P$name,  get.edge.attribute(g, "name"))]) 

#Edges are now correct
get.edge.attribute(g3)matrix(adjmat, nrow = 4) 
get.vertex.attribute(g3)
```

Is there a function in igraph that would merge the two seperate networks into a single network whilst maintaining the attributes as is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have made the below version of union, which accepts two graphs with an arbitrary number of overlapping attributes and merges them into a single graph where the attributes do not have the "_x" suffix. The graphs can be entirely independent or have overlapping nodes.
In the case of overlapping nodes the attributes of graph 1 take precedence

```
library(dplyr)
library(igraph)

union2<-function(g1, g2){

 #Internal function that cleans the names of a given attribute
 CleanNames <- function(g, target){
  #get target names
  gNames <- parse(text = (paste0(target,"_attr_names(g)"))) %>% eval 
  #find names that have a "_1" or "_2" at the end
  AttrNeedsCleaning <- grepl("(_\\d)$", gNames )
  #remove the _x ending
  StemName <- gsub("(_\\d)$", "", gNames)

  NewnNames <- unique(StemName[AttrNeedsCleaning])
  #replace attribute name for all attributes
  for( i in NewnNames){

   attr1 <- parse(text = (paste0(target,"_attr(g,'", paste0(i, "_1"),"')"))) %>% eval
   attr2 <- parse(text = (paste0(target,"_attr(g,'", paste0(i, "_2"),"')"))) %>% eval

   g <- parse(text = (paste0("set_",target,"_attr(g, i, value = ifelse(is.na(attr1), attr2, attr1))"))) %>%
             eval

   g <- parse(text = (paste0("delete_",target,"_attr(g,'", paste0(i, "_1"),"')"))) %>% eval
   g <- parse(text = (paste0("delete_",target,"_attr(g,'", paste0(i, "_2"),"')"))) %>% eval

   }

  return(g)
 }


 g <- igraph::union(g1, g2) 
 #loop through each attribute type in the graph and clean
 for(i in c("graph", "edge", "vertex")){
 g <- CleanNames(g, i)
 }

 return(g)

}
```

Using the previous example

```
g4 <-union2(gList[[1]], gList[[2]])

#As we would like
get.edge.attribute(g4)
get.vertex.attribute(g4)
```

Comment: Great answer. Could this be extended to accept a list of `n` graphs?

Comment: Use Reduce(union2, list(...)). Then each graph in the list will be merged into a single graph. I think we had a very similar problem!